# restricting display of some data to user

Tags: python, html, database, django, templates

how do I restrict what a user can view in a web browser? Say the user wants to retrieve data from the database but not everything, just a few say if there are 4 data columns, the user can only view 3? How can I do that?

Am using Django's class-based views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defer`  in your django query set like

```
Entry.objects.defer("headline", "body")
```

above query will not contain the columns headline and body from Entry table

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the admin interface, you can use the [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) attribute of the `ModelAdmin` class to describe which fields to display.

There are similar attributes for `ModelForm` objects such as the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your view:

```
is_trusted = request.user.groups.filter(name='Trusted')
```

pass it to template, and in your template:

```
{% if is_trusted %} Show full table {% else %} Show simple table {% endif %}
```